# Interpolating data fails: grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values

Tags: matlab, 2d, interpolation, time-frequency

I have some time/frequency data and I try to interpolate it using the `interp2` function of Matlab. The data `[F,T,data]` is obtained from a different Matlab routine of Matlab, spectrogram in case you are interested.

```
[~,F,T,data] = spectrogram(...)
data = 10*log10(data);
```

I can plot the data using `surf`. The data is fine, I believe. However interpolating the data seems to be a problem. Even using `interp2(F,T,data,F,T)` (so actually no interpolating) gives the error below.

What is going wrong here?

I have the data which I use here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr5zpfhp6qyarzw/test.mat

```
interp2(F,T,data,f,t)
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.
Error in interp2>makegriddedinterp (line 228)
    F = griddedInterpolant(varargin{:});
Error in interp2 (line 128)
        F = makegriddedinterp({X, Y}, V, method,extrap);
>> size(F),size(T),size(data),size(f),size(t)
ans =
   129     1
ans =
     1    52
ans =
   129    52
ans =
   200     1
ans =
     1   121
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should swap `F` and `T`:

```
interp2(T,F,data,t,f);
```

The first argument corresponds with the columns of the matrix and the second argument with the rows as documented [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html#input_argument_d0e499887):

> If X and Y are grid vectors, then V must be a matrix containing
>   length(Y) rows and length(X) columns.

As an **alternative**, you may take the transpose of `data`:

```
interp2(F,T,data',f,t);
```

**Reasoning behind (strange) argument order**

`interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)` is interpreted as the interpolation of a *function*, represented by the *matrix* V, i.e. the sample values. The problem is that the arguments/indexes of a function/matrix are rather supplied in an opposite order:

```
matrix(row, column)
```

versus

```
function(x,y)
```

`x` (first argument) often represents the horizontal axes and therefore corresponds with the `column` (second argument) argument and idem for `y` and `row`.